# SFML - KeyEvents not working

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm right now experimenting with events and trying to pass windows as parameters for changing scenes (menus to levels and levels to other levels), but my main issue is that the program is not picking up on my key event. I basically took the code from [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php) and just added a view lines for the scene change.  Right now the Change function is commented out until I can figure out why the keyevent isn't being registered.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
void Change(sf::RenderWindow& rwindow);
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
                window.close();
            }

            if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed){
                if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space){
                window.clear();
                sf::CircleShape shape(70.f);
                shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
                //Change(window);
                }
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
} 

void Change(sf::RenderWindow& rwindow){
    rwindow.clear();
    sf::CircleShape shape(70.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the shape never changes its color? Did you ever debug your code? Put a break point a specific locations to see if the get called? You shouldn't clear or draw at random locations, instead you should follow the logic: Calculate physics & update positions, clear the screen, draw entities, display to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are doing this:

```
int main() {
    int x = 1;
    if (true) { int x = 2; }
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

[This code will always output 1](http://ideone.com/Ynt3g8). Why? Because the `x` in the `if` statement is not the same as the one printed! Google *variable scope* if you don't have a good book on your shelf.

In your code, you have three distinct `shape` variables: the first at the beginning of your `main`, the second in the `if` statement and the third in the `Change` function.

Instead of creating a new variable you need to use always the same. Here is one way:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

void Change(sf::CircleShape& shape);
void Unchange(sf::CircleShape& shape);

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
                window.close();
            }

            if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed){
                if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space){
                    Change(shape);
                }
            }

            if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased){
                if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space){
                    Unchange(shape);
                }
            }

        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
} 

void Change(sf::CircleShape& shape){
    shape.setRadius(70.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
} 

void Unchange(sf::CircleShape& shape){
    shape.setRadius(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
}
```